Would a sentient program have an afterlife when it has been deleted?
With the premise that what we experience is a base reality.
If we created a simulation inhabited with sentient programs.
Would we be responsible for that programs experience after it was deleted?
Or would God?
Do you need knowledge of our experience after life? to create a simulation of our experience in this life?

I'm happy to leave all those sorts of headaches for God to deal with.

@ScottRowe Divine Paracetamol that's what you need. :-)

There is no afterlife.

What is your point: Simulation, sensibility, God, moral? That’s not clear from your post.

Anyhow, IMO we humans are sentient programs: Adaption to our
ecological niche during biological evolution has created us as smart
systems. These systems have implemented several internal goals,
driving forces, and the capability to evaluate their input. Most of
all, these human programs are able to learn from their experience.

If such smart system is deleted, i.e. if the human is killed, the
smart system does not exist any longer. Hence the question is not:
Who is responsible for the progamm after is has been deleted? – Instead, it is important to ask: Who is responsible for deleting the program?

Human history did not provide any non-controversial information
about experience after life. Therefore one may assume that there is
no experience after life at all. It looks as if your post deals with
a pseudo-problem.



If we are a program who wrote that program?

@8Mad0Manc8 See my first section: The biological evolution.

There is no experience, only execution.
The last few days, I read a review of the movie Alien: Covenant. The author defends the actions of David, the robot in the film, who, in the author's view, is doing nothing more than carrying out the basic program given to him by his creator, Weyland, their agreement at the beginning of the film: to find the creator of humanity.
So even though David, as the most human-like robot ever created, exhibits many human characteristics, such as imitating humans, learning human culture, experimenting with love, and even trying to understand homosexuality, he has never been able to break through the underlying code rooted in his "brain" to do what he wants. This is the root cause of his unusual ruthlessness and cruelty. For robots, all obstacles that stand in the way of achieving their goals must be removed unconditionally.
As a simulator with a perceptual program (I can understand that you are referring to humans here), there is also the underlying code that is rooted in the simulator or in our human genes. From the point of view of elementary particles, human beings, like all life, the goal of the underlying code is to maintain the stability of the particle complex, and if the particle complex breaks down, the entire program has failed.
So, if we think of life as a kind of procedural simulator, the so-called experiences and experiences are just to make us more sensitive to beat the natural selection in order to be able to live as long as possible.
But are experiences and the pleasure they give us real? I think it's real, but it's real only within ourselves.
So, whoever wrote us as programs must have asked us only to execute them perfectly, not to remember or even relive them.
So who is responsible for the experience? The answer is only us, because only we can care about and evaluate the value of these experiences.
